# Excel macro for loop?

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing a macro in excel and I have a 10 by 10 grid that I need to input a vlookup equation into. So for the first column of data I wrote a for loop

```
For i = 2 to 11
     Cells (i, 30) = "=vlookup (E2" & i & ", B:C, 2, False)" 
Next i
```

And it works the way I want it. Now I would like to write an outer for loop that will allow me to go across the columns.

I started with

```
For j = 30 to 39
    For i = 2 to 11
         Cells (i, 30) = "=vlookup (E" & i & ", B:C, 2, False)" 
    Next i
Next j
```

But I need E to change to F and I can't figure out how to do that.

I also tried using the `Range (Cells(__,__),Cells(__,__)).FormulaR1C1 =...`

But I couldn't get that to work either, since it is moving the table as well as fixing E2 across the columns.

If anyone can help I would greatly appreciate it. If not I will just write 10 for loops one for each column.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is create the first formula and add "$" to appropriately anchor the reference rows/columns at which point you can simply copy the formula across the desired rows/columns.

here is a quick synopsis of anchoring: http://excelonthegrid.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/anchor-with-dollars/

i can give you the final answers if you post the desired formula for 
a) column 1 row 1
b) column 1 row 2
c) column 2 row 1
d) column 2 row 2